# v-navigation-drawer drops into a runaway loop on window resize

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

First, let me say that the v-navigation-drawer works as intended, i.e.:

- On **clicking** the hamburger menu the TOGGLE_DRAWER mutation is committed, and it toggles open/closed, updating the state.
- On **window resize** it opens/closes at a designated breakpoint

So it works.

**BUT** the window resize does not properly toggle the mutation and I keep getting a Vuex mutation error when I resize the window:

[image]

I understand why I'm getting this error - the `$store.state.ui.drawer` is being modified outside of the mutator (it's the v-navigation-drawer's `v-model`):

```
<v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="$store.state.ui.drawer"
        app
        clipped
    >
```

I get it's bad form to bind the state to the v-model. But when I try to make a `drawer` computed property with a `get()` and `set()` method that properly gets/commits a mutation, the browser crashes (presumably because the set method triggers an endless loop of commits toggling `drawer` true/false into infinity):

```
computed: { 
            drawer: {
                get () {
                    return this.$store.state.ui.drawer
                },
                set () {
                    this.$store.commit('TOGGLE_DRAWER') // <--crashes the browser
                }
            }
        }
```

I've searched endlessly for a solution to this problem. It's bugging me even though it visually appears to be working.

I've considered running the v-navigation-drawer in [stateless](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#stateless) mode and handling all the window resize events and state updates manually. I've also considered disabling 'Strict' mode in Vuex (which would hide the errors). But the former is a lot more complexity and the latter is a bandaid that costs me debugging insight in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time with this, I think I have a solution. Wanted to share for anyone else that may be facing the same issue with VNavigationDrawer using Vuex state to control visibility.

The `@input` event passes a `val` parameter, which includes the state of the drawer after the window resizes. I created a new action that is called by the below function:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    :value="$store.state.ui.drawer"
    app
    clipped
    @input="updateDrawer($event)"
>
```

Here is the action being dispatched:

```
methods: {
    updateDrawer(event) {
        if (event !== this.drawer) { // avoids dispatching duplicate actions; checks for unique window resize event
            this.$store.dispatch('updateDrawer',event)
        }
    }
},
```

And the action commits the new `val` to the Vuex store.

Basically, the input event is able to watch for updates to the drawer, and subsequently update the drawer state if it's necessary.

You'll also see above that I stubbornly accepted using `:value` as the [docs suggest](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers), even though I think this should be controlled by a v-model.

Seems to be working - with the right events called and the state being updated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for [Lodash's `debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) function. If you need to stick with using setter/getter while applying this effect, have a look at [this post](/a/44780866/3634538); otherwise, [this one](/a/54854751/3634538) for sequential event subscription on any of the lifecycle hooks.